# Creating custom AlertDialog Box height and width

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create custom height and weight with scrollview of custom alertdialog box but it's doesn't work for me. Can anyone explain me how to create custom alertdialog box custom weight and height with scrollview? Is there any wrong code on my xml file?

.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="268dp"
    android:id="@+id/zonevi_clubs"
    android:layout_margin="30dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="268dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/club1"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/club3"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club5"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/club5"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/club8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club7"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my custom alertdialog as follow:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.zonevi_clubs, null);

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Thank You", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's My Pleasure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setView(view);
                    builder.show();
```

Comment: You set same height for root layout & scrollview so it wont scroll until your scrollview height is larger than root layout(Relative layout). & scrollview cannot hold multiple views as child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`ScrollView`** has Direct only one child

Wrap all the **`ImageView`** inside of  **`LinearLayout`** like below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/zonevi_clubs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="268dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/club1"
                android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club3"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/club3"
                android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club4"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club5"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/club5"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/club8"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club6"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club7"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**java code**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.zonevi_clubs, null);
builder.setView(view);
AlertDialog dialog_card = build.create();
Window window = dialog_card.getWindow();
window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,268);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
build.show();
```

Comment: it's not work for me can u tell me in .java file how i will custom size the java code is above

Comment: @Keshab happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="268dp"
android:id="@+id/zonevi_clubs"
android:layout_margin="30dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="268dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" /* 4(100dp) * 2 height of imageview. */ 
    android:id="@+id/zonevi_clubs_scroll_root"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/club1"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/club3"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/club5"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/club8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club7"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_rtr" />
</ScrollView>
```